# Windows 7: How to change XP Mode settings

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, windows-xp-mode

I've been trying to enable "undo disks" on my Windows 7 XP Mode virtual machine.

Because this is one of the settings that cannot be updated while the VM is running I've tried shutting it down. Unfortunately when I try to shutdown the machine it just disappears.

What steps do I need to take to change the settings om the XP Mode VM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the VM in your profile under "Virtual Machines". There you can simply right-click "Windows XP Mode" and choose "Settings" from the context menu.

Comment: I found it at Users\<username>\Virtual Machines - thanks

Comment: Eep, you're right. I corrected the path. Also the link to "Windows Virtual PC" in the start menu does nothing else than open Explorer in that folder. Quite nice integration, I have to admit.